# BSDF - need an example

Tags: c++, graphics, 3d, rendering, raytracing

I'm trying to understand in a simple raytracer what does the [BSDF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bidirectional_scattering_distribution_function) function does and in theory I got it but in practice I don't know how to implement one.

Can someone point me out some simple examples (well-explained if possible) on how to use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check PBRT project. It is great book, but if you do not want to read it, there is well documented source code availabe: [PBRT](http://www.pbrt.org/)